# How to add "-" bettween numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am extracting words containing both numbers and letters from a string

> Input:  'This is 78acb78 test result1 and 1test'.
>
> Output for requirement 1:
> Matched Words: '78acb78 , result1 , 1test'

Now i am able to find the word including both numbers and letters.

But I want to achieve the output with '-' character. With the matched words , we need to add "-" before or after it depend on the position. If at the top of sentence, we will add "-" after numbers and opposite with the end of the sentence. If it present between, we always have "-" before + after + both of them ( 3 cases ).

> Output for requirement 2:
> ' 78-acb78 , 78-acb-78 , 78acb-78 , result-1 ,1-test '

How can I get the output like this? This is my code now.

```js
let str = 'This is 78acb78 test result1 and 1test';

// ^               # start of input
// (?=.*?\d)       # lookahead to make sure at least one digit is there
// (?=.*?[a-zA-Z]) # lookahead to make sure at least one letter is there
// [a-zA-Z\d]+     # regex to match 1 or more of digit or letters
// $               # end of input

const checkWordMatched = (str) => {
    let strRegex = /^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]+$/;
    let wordMatched = (str.split(" ")).filter(word => {
        if (strRegex.test(word)) {
            return word;
        }
    })
    return wordMatched;
}

const processText = (inputText) => {
    let checkNumber = /^[\d]+$/;
    let newText = inputText.match(/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/gi);
    return newText;
}
let newArr = checkWordMatched(str);
let newRes = [];

console.log("Matched Words:" + newArr);
const result = newArr.map(item => {
    return processText(item);
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: are you sure this is output you want `78-acb78 , 78-acb-78 , 78acb-78 , result-1 ,1-test ` ? Because your output requirement is **contradicting** with what you said here: *But I want to achieve the output with '-' character. The hyphen character should be between numbers and letters.*

Comment: yeah, my english is bad so i can't write description clearly, sorry. I'm sure that i want the output like i write above.

Comment: is there a pattern we need to look out? or the data are always these three matched words? could data be added with more words in the future?

Comment: data can be added with more words depend on your input. At present i just want to process with words include letters and numbers ( not include special charater ). With numbers in the word , we need to add "-" before or after it depend on the position. If at the top of sentence, we will add "-" after numbers and opposite with the end of the sentence. If it present between, we always have "-" before + after + both of them ( 3 cases ).

Answer (score 0):

Please see the possible solution for your required output.
let me know if you need any further help. thanks

```js
let str0 = "This is 78acb78 test result1 and 1test";
        let str1 = "This is 78acb78 test result1 and 1test";
        

        /* Answer to output 1 >> extracting alphanumeric only from string*/
        function extractAlphanumericOnly(str){
            
                
            /*converting string to array*/
            str = str.split(' ');
            
            /*removing only alpha values from array*/
            for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
              
              if (!/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(str[i])){
                 str.splice(i,1,'');
              }else{
                /*else code here*/
              }

            }
            
            /*removing indexes with space only*/
            str = str.filter(function(str) {
                return /\S/.test(str);
            });
            
            return str;

        }

        /* Answer to output 2 >> adding hyphen "-" with alpha numeric */
        function addDashToAlphanumericValues(str){
            

            /*separating and makign array of characters and numbers*/
            str = str.match(/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/gi);


            /*removing indexes with space only*/
            str = str.filter(function(str) {
                return /\S/.test(str);
            });

            /*removing space within values */
            str = str.map(function (el) {
                return el.trim();
            });

            /* converting to string, replacing commas with '-' character*/
            return str = str.toString().split(',').join('-');
        
        }


        console.log("Output for requirement1: " + extractAlphanumericOnly(str0));
        console.log("Output for requirement 2: " + addDashToAlphanumericValues(str1));
```

Comment: sorry to not give clearly detail question. I just edited and give more detail for this question. Tks for your help but not match my requirement. With the matched words , we need to add "-" before or after it depend on the position. If at the top of sentence, we will add "-" after numbers and opposite with the end of the sentence. If it present between, we always have "-" before + after + both of them ( 3 cases ).

Comment: ok no worries, my answer is according to output requirement. You may run my code and can see your required output

Comment: This is my requirement : '78acb78,result1,1test' => ' 78-acb78 , 78-acb-78 , 78acb-78 , result-1 ,1-test '

Comment: This is your answer: 'This-is-78-acb-78-test-result-1-and-1-test'. Don't match at all.

Comment: requirement 2 is base on result of requirement 1

Comment: got your point, but one output is according to your requirement and one output is not. will make second output according to your requirement soon

Comment: thanks for your help, hope to hear something great from you soon